# c++11 std array - differences between gcc and visual studio

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, std

I have a problem with this part of code:

```
typedef std::array<u32, 3> my_array;

void foo()
{
    my_array a1{{1, 2, 3}};
    a1 = {{1, 2, 3}}; // PROBLEM - does not work;

    my_array a2{{3, 2, 1}};
    a1 = a2;
}
```

GCC 4.7 compiles this code as well, but Visual studio with cl from November 2012 fails with:

```
 error C2679: binary '=' : no operator found which takes a right-hand
 operand of type 'initializer-list' (or there is no acceptable
 conversion) 1>        C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
 11.0\VC\INCLUDE\array(211): could be 'std::array<u32,3> &std::array<u32,3>::operator =(const std::array<u32,3> &)' 1>       
 while trying to match the argument list '(my_array, initializer-list)'
```

Is this syntax correct and agreed with c++11 standard? I cannot find any informations about this and do not know which compiler I should blame. Thanks in advance for help.

Best regards.

Comment: VS2012 is a little on the lame with C++11....

Comment: VS2012 doesn't support initializer lists - see here - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/vstudio/hh567368.aspx

Answer (score 1):

As I stated, `VS2012` is a little lame and has some difficulties with `C++11`, if you want a list, look [here](http://cpprocks.com/c11-compiler-support-shootout-visual-studio-gcc-clang-intel/).

Comment: Hi,im using compiler from http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35515 which has intializer_list support.

Comment: Maybe it is a bug. I had similar issues, though

Comment: @user2311165: You don't think the fact that you were using the Nov12 CTP was worth mentioning?  Anyway, this is from blog post announcing that CTP release: "This package contains only the compiler, and does not yet come with an updated standard library to use the features (such as a std::vector initializer_list constructor)"

Comment: I knew there was something fishy about this. Thank you very much, Michael Burr